# OOP - Modeling a Chat Design Review

Tags: java, design-patterns, object-oriented, object-oriented-design, chat

Seeking thoughts on the following design.
I know the design could be lot simpler if use Sockets. But I wanted to think of a design with pure POJO classes.

**User**

```
string id;
string displayname;
```

**ChatWindow**

```
User user;
ChatManager room; //interface to access ChatRoom
readDeliveryReceipts  boolean;
LinkedHashMap<id-userid, AcknowledgeMessage>messages;
Message currentMessage;
displayMessage(Message message);//Adds an entry to logs 
acknowledgeMessage (String messageId);
acceptAcknowledgement(String messageId);
```

**Message** → TextMessage , Video Message , Audio Message   (inheritance)

```
-string id;
-DateTime timestamp;
-User user;
-string text;
```

**AcknowledgeMessage** (use decorator Pattern) //Store Message logs

```
-Message msg;
-Type (ServerAccepted , SentToClient);
```

**ChatManager**  //An Adapter Class to interact with ChatRoom

```
ChatRoom room;
sendMessage(Message message);
register(ChatWindow window);
deregister(ChatWindow window);
acknowledgeMessage(String messageId);
```

**ChatRoom (Chat Session)**

```
List<ChatWindow> chatWindows;
BlockedQueue<Messages> messagesToSend;

//Listener Pattern
register(ChatWindow window);
deregister(ChatWindow window); 

receivingMessage(Message); //will add it to the Queue and send acknowledgement
//Listener Pattern
sendMessage(Message);   //Will iterate all the chatwindows
```

Comment: This isn't [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but I suppose your interface definitions (???) aren't "code" (particularly with the strange inconsistent semi-colon usage).  Please clarify ***what** it is that you are asking*.

Comment: What do sockets have to do with anything? They are a mechanism of delivering messages, there is nothing about them that would not allow you do have a POJO-based application...

Comment: Please read: **[Are Design Review questions on-topic?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6502)**